# Where is the OS name stored, and how can I edit it?

Tags: custom-distributions, editing, tweak

As question says, I am looking for file that holds system name (note: not hostname)

and by that I mean, where it comes from "Ubuntu" "Ubuntu 13.10" and so on...

Is there any way to change it? For example, to change Ubuntu to SomeDummyLinuxOS...

Comment: system name is precisely the hostname. Plz make it clear where do you want to show the change from "Ubuntu" to "SomeDummyLinuxOS"

Comment: You know, i try to build whole ubuntu distro from scratch, just for reason to try to understand better how ubuntu system works internaly, how files get connected and so on... anyway, i found file responsible for what i need. It is located in /etc/lsb-release

Answer (score 1):

Name and version of the operating system visible in virtual consoles is stored in `/etc/issue`.

Comment: issue file is used only, and only for loging message after starting console, or after logging out from console. Press ctrl+alt+f1 and try it yourself. These files I asked for are /etc/lsb-release and /etc/os-release but thanks for trying.